# What's faster to parse lots of data (5Mb): eval or json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, eval

I want to get, via ajax, a collection of data objects and parse them into JS data.

Currently I have 2 choices:
 - Server returns valid javascript code and then I eval it.
 - Server returns JSON object and then I eval the json object

What is the fastest of these in Firefox? (I only care about the "parsing" performance, not server or data transfer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [the results VinylFox came up](http://www.vinylfox.com/json-decoding-speed-comparison/) with when he tested JSON decoding in the wild. The native functions performed best across *all* browsers.

Comment: Anyone know of a more up-to-date comparison that also considers simply loading javascript (e.g. via a script tag or, effectively, require or equivalent?)

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox 3.5+ there is a native json parsing function `window.JSON.parse` - this would likely be the fastest. In older browsers, you might have better luck with `(new Function("return "+json))()`

Comment: Chrome also has a native JSON parser (same API).

Comment: Most modern browsers do, I was just answering the "What is the fastest of these in Firefox question" - but yea, most new browsers have this. You can test with `if (JSON && JSON.parse){}`